# Installation of my custom Debian ISO failed

Tags: debian, iso

I followed [this tutorial](http://silicone.homelinux.org/2013/06/19/building-a-custom-debian-cd/) to create my custom Debian CD with build-simple-cdd, but I get always an error, even if I use the basic config.

The ISO file is created (named debian-7.3-amd64-CD-1.iso),
but when I try to install it I get the following error:

```
Avertissement: Failure trying to run: chroot /target dpkg --force-depends --install  /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_7.1wheezy4_amd64.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/base-passwd_3.5.26_amd64.deb
```

<sup>("avertissement" is French for "warning".)</sup>

```
$ cat package-list | grep base
acpi-support-base                               install
alsa-base                                       install
base-files                                      install
base-passwd                                     install
desktop-base                                    install
dnsmasq-base                                    install
exim4-base                                      install
gcc-4.7-base:amd64                              install
geoip-database                                  install
gettext-base                                    install
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10                    install
groff-base                                      install
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64                install
libfile-basedir-perl                            install
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64           install
libilmbase6                                     install
libreoffice-base                                install
libreoffice-base-core                           install
libsnmp-base                                    install
libxml-sax-base-perl                            install
linux-base                                      install
lsb-base                                        install
ncurses-base                                    install
netbase                                         install
perl-base                                       install
powermgmt-base                                  install
sgml-base                                       install
xfonts-base                                     install
```

Error on virtual terminal (Alt+F4):

[image]

Comment: I try to install it on virtualbox virtual machine for testing

Comment: Are there any other error messages? Say on virtual terminal 3 or 4 (Alt-F3 or Alt-F4)?

Comment: During the creation of the custom cd, you ran `dpkg --get-selections >package-list` to make a list of the packages right? if you `grep base package-list` you find `base-files` and `base-passwd` as a result on your screen?

Comment: @nwildner: you can see my question update

Comment: @derobert: you can my update about error diplayed on virtual terminal 4 (alt-F4)

Comment: And does any install try created a file called `/tmp/install.log` file? Could you please upload it on pastebin? It seems that or your dpkg is having problem on proccess dependencies of `base-files` and `base-passwd` or it have some issues on your target system hard drive(mounted as /target to receive the package contents/installation).

Comment: I don't found install.log in my /tmp folder